# Azure VM Backup of v2 Hosts?

Tags: azure, backup

I have 16 VMs running Win Sever 2012. Some were created with ARM templates, some manually in the new portal.
I need to now get them all discovered by Azure Backup so they cab be captured at the "VM level". These new
VMs do not show up in the classic portal and do not show as "discovered".

Does scripting exist that can force the discovery so I can make VM-level backups of these resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

V2 VM backup in Resource Group

Its available now 
check with this link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm/

Comment: This is link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible! There is simply no visibility from the Service Management backup to resource management VMs

I have some workarounds in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/733863/backup-workaround-for-iaas-v2-virtual-machines-on-azure/734362#734362) question.

And according to Azure it is started on the [feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/258995-azure-backup-and-scdpm/suggestions/8369907-azure-backup-to-support-iaas-vm-v2). It is frustrating that they've released v2 without backup support, but we just need to work around it for now.